# Scroller acting different regarding his first child

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5, scroller

im' facing a strange issue with Scroller in my application.

I'm using for my forms scrollers like this :

```
<s:Group id="mainGrp" width="100%" height="100%"  >
    <s:Scroller id="scroller" width="100%" bottom="50" top="30" >
        <s:Group id="childrenGrp" width="100%" height="100%" >
            <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" paddingTop="15" paddingLeft="20" gap="20" paddingRight="10" paddingBottom="10">
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Group>
```

With this example, my scroll bar (with mouse wheel) is quite slow. If i remove the container Group with id "childrenGrp", i 've got a normal speed but the padding on the Vgroup make the scroller in some strange state (impossible to go to the top and the bottom of the container).

My questions are :

1/ Why the scroll speed change regarding scroller's first child ? (group make it slow, and vgroup is normal)

2/Why paddingTop and paddingBottom on scroller's first child make the scroller unusable ?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For number 1 I don't have an exact answer, but you could try this: Capture the mousewheel event and trace the event.delta (the amount of lines the mousewheel scroll moves the bar)

```
    protected function foo_mouseWheelHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace(event.delta);
    }
```

Is the amount different on both cases (with or without the group)

Comment: Thx for your reply. I didn't mention that i've already checked this, and without any reason the result is the same (-3/+3)